# What remainder does $34!$ leave when divided by $71$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial, chinese-remainder-theorem

What is the remainder of $34!$ when divided by $71$?
Is there an objective way of solving this?

I came across a solution which straight away starts by stating that
$69!$ mod $71$ equals $1$ and I lost it right there.

Comment: The reason it's true is because of Wilson's theorem if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Like Jack said, [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) gives $70!\equiv -1\pmod{71}$. The last factor $70$ is congruent to $-1$ modulo $71$, so if you remove that (divide by the unit $-1$) in the congruence, you have $69!\equiv +1\pmod{71}$. So that was the start. I don't know how your source continued from there to find $34!$.

Comment: [this](http://oeis.org/A004055) is a relevant list.  I'm not seeing any easy way to resolve the double-solution you get when solving the quadratic.

Comment: [another](http://oeis.org/A073944) somewhat relevant oeis.

Comment: @Goos See [this OEIS sequence.](https://oeis.org/A058302) and [this one.](https://oeis.org/A055939)

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks, I should have thought to search for the actual primes in question.

Answer (score 11):

While we can certainly show that $35! \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{71}$,
deciding between these two is apparently far from elementary.
This has been dealt with [on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16141/primes-p-such-that-p-1-2-1-mod-p),
and the answers there give the following formula,
if $p > 3$ is a prime congruent to $3$ mod $4$:
$$
\left( \frac{p-1}{2} \right)!
= (-1)^{(1 + h(-p))/2}
$$
with $h(-p)$ denoting the [Class number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html) of the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$.
In this case
the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-71})$ is $7$ (source: [1](http://www.numbertheory.org/classnos/), [2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NumberFieldClassNumber%5BSqrt%5B-71%5D%5D)),
so we have
$$
35! \equiv (-1)^{\left( 1 + 7 \right)/2} = 1 \pmod{71}
$$
and
$$
34! \equiv (35)^{-1} 35! = (-2)(1) \equiv \boxed{69} \pmod{71}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

From $$69!=1\mod 71\Rightarrow 34!36!=-1\mod 71$$ Multiplying both sides by $4$ and noting that $35\cdot 2=-1\mod 71,\ 36\cdot 2=1\mod 71$, we get $$(34!)^2=4\mod 71\Rightarrow x^2=4\mod 71$$ where $34!=x\mod 71$ So, $$71|(x-2)(x+2)\Rightarrow x+2=71, or \ x=2\Rightarrow x=69\ or\ 2$$ since $1\le x\le 70$.

Comment: Not so fast.  How do you know $x$ isn't $2$?

Comment: Oh, correct that is  a possibility too. Thanks.

Comment: Well, which is it? :D

Comment: I am trying to find.

Comment: The ambiguity here is infuriating.  So close to an answer, yet there seems no way to reduce down to just one option.

Comment: I started writing up an answer because I thought I had solved it, then I realized I couldn't get rid of the $\pm$ in $\pm\, 2$ ...

Comment: Yes @Goos. It seems there is no immediate way to answer which one is the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah, for any prime $p$ of the form $4k+3$, from Wilson's theorem we get $-1 \equiv (p-1)! \equiv -(((p-1)/2)!)^2$ so $((p-1)/2)! \equiv \pm 1$. But running through primes of this form with a computer shows no clear pattern of which sign occurs when.

Comment: I've got a terribly ugly solution using stuff like $285 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 19 = 71 \cdot 4 + 1$ ...

Comment: What solution did you get?

Comment: $-2$. I used factors of $70$, $72$, $143$, $285$, $425$, and $496$ to reduce it.

Comment: Seems like a tough job.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing in the line of Samrat Mukhopadhyay's answer, a method that is hardly any easier than actually computing $34!\pmod{71}$ by simply multiplying factor by factor:

By Wilson's theorem we know that $70!\equiv-1\pmod{71}$, from which it follows that
$$(34!)^2\times35\times36\equiv34!\times36!\equiv70!\equiv-1\pmod{71}.$$
Because $2\times35\equiv-1\pmod{71}$ and $2\times36\equiv1\pmod{71}$ we see that
$$(34!)^2\equiv-4\times(34!)^2\times35\times36\equiv4\pmod{71},$$
which shows that $34!\equiv\pm2\pmod{71}$.

Note that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $71$ as $71\equiv3\pmod{4}$. However $2$ is a quadratic residue because $71\equiv-1\pmod{8}$, and therefore $-2$ is *not* a quadratic residue modulo $71$. Some hand counting shows that the square-free part of $34!$ equals
$$3\times5\times11\times19\times23\times29\times31.$$
So the question is now whether this is a quadratic residue modulo $71$. By the law of quadratic reciprocity, and using the fact that $19\equiv3\pmod{8}$ and $23\equiv-1\pmod{8}$, we see that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\frac{3}{71}\right)&=&-\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)=1,\\
\left(\frac{5}{71}\right)&=&\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)=1,\\
\left(\frac{11}{71}\right)&=&-\left(\frac{5}{11}\right)=-\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)=-1,\\
\left(\frac{19}{71}\right)&=&-\left(\frac{14}{19}\right)=-\left(\frac{2}{19}\right)\left(\frac{7}{19}\right)=-\left(\frac{5}{7}\right)=-\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)=1,\\
\left(\frac{23}{71}\right)&=&-\left(\frac{2}{23}\right)=-1,\\
\left(\frac{29}{71}\right)&=&\left(\frac{13}{29}\right)=\left(\frac{3}{13}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=1,\\
\left(\frac{31}{71}\right)&=&-\left(\frac{9}{31}\right)=-1.
\end{eqnarray*}
We find an odd number of non-squares in the product above, which shows that it is *not* a quadratic residue modulo $71$, and hence $34!\equiv-2\equiv69\pmod{71}$.

Comment: +1!  I had thought of using quadratic residues to resolve the choice between $2$ and $-2$ but didn't think of doing it like this.